# Creating a linked list program from user's input

Tags: c++

We are asked to make a program using list structure to list student information but I can't seem to find a way to output all of it. It only shows one and it is the last input. I'm new in doing linked list so I do not know how to manipulate them. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you guys!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){

struct StudList{
string studID, studName, Course;
int Yr_level;

StudList *next;
};

StudList *head;
head = NULL;

StudList *stud;
StudList *studptr;

int studNum;
system("color F0");
cout << "Enter number of stuedents: ";
cin >> studNum;

for (int i=1; i<=studNum; i++)
{
    stud = new StudList;

    cout << "\nEnter Student ID   : ";
    cin >> stud -> studID;
    cout << "Enter Student Name : ";
    cin >> stud -> studName;
    cout << "Course             : ";
    cin >> stud -> Course;
    cout << "Year Level         : ";
    cin >> stud -> Yr_level;

    stud -> next = NULL;
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "\nThe students are: ";
while (stud != NULL)
{
    cout << endl << endl << left << setw(10) << stud -> studID << setw(10) << stud -> studName <<
    setw(8) << stud -> Course << setw(4) << stud -> Yr_level;
    stud = stud -> next;
}

if (head == NULL)
{
    head == stud;
}
else
{
    studptr = head;

    while (studptr -> next)
    {
        studptr = studptr -> next;
    }
    studptr -> next = stud;
    }
    }
```

Comment: In the `for` loop where you enter student information you don't connect newly created `stud` to the list itself (you should keep the *tail* of your list, and save a pointer of `stud` at `tail->next` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for` loop you should save new `stud` object for setting `stud->next` during next iteration.

In `while` loop you are checking only last created `stud` object. You must set `stud` for the first object from the list, you can use `head` object for that to save first list element.

I think that if `(head == NULL) ...` part is not necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){

struct StudList{
string studID, studName, Course;
int Yr_level;

StudList *next;
};

StudList *head;
head = NULL;

StudList *stud;

int studNum;
system("color F0");
cout << "Enter number of stuedents: ";
cin >> studNum;



StudList * temp = nullptr;
for (int i=1; i<=studNum; i++)
{
    
    stud = new StudList;
    if ( i == 1 ) 
        {head = stud;}
    else
        {temp->next = stud;}
    
        
    cout << "\nEnter Student ID   : ";
    cin >> stud -> studID;
    cout << "Enter Student Name : ";
    cin >> stud -> studName;
    cout << "Course             : ";
    cin >> stud -> Course;
    cout << "Year Level         : ";
    cin >> stud -> Yr_level;
    
    stud -> next = NULL;
    temp = stud;
    cout << endl;
}

stud = head;

cout << "\nThe students are: ";
while (stud != NULL)
{
    cout << endl << endl << left << setw(10) << stud -> studID << setw(10) << stud -> studName <<
    setw(8) << stud -> Course << setw(4) << stud -> Yr_level;
    stud = stud -> next;
}

}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! I will take note of this next time!